# aspnet 6 webapplication run on docker windows with ssl cert binding

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, powershell, iis

I have a requirement to create a docker image for aspnet 6 web application to run on Docker container, however code is tightly coupled with SSL cert, the service wont start if there is no SSL binding.
How can i achieve to have SSL binding enabled when service starts?

I have tried IIS image by creating a website on IIS and binding the site with certiticate, service doesnt start.

Here is the docker file which I have been trying with image 2016,2019,2022

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2016
EXPOSE 443
WORKDIR '/inetpub/wwwroot'
COPY . .
ENV CERT_PASSWORD=tripspark
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
    powershell -NoProfile -Command New-Website -Name 'auth' -IPAddress '*' -Port 443 -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' -ApplicationPool 'DefaultAppPool' -Ssl -SslFlags 0; \
    icacls 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)F'; \
    powershell.exe -Command "\
        Import-Module IISAdministration; \
        Import-Module WebAdministration; \
        $cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\localhost.pfx' -CertStoreLocation cert:\localMachine\My -password (ConvertTo-SecureString $env:CERT_PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force); \
        new-item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\*!443 -value $cert -Confirm:$false; \
    "
```

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.